# Read csv file with same header in r

Tags: r, read.table, read.csv

I have multiple csv files with same header but those headers contain spaced in between. Is it possible to read these headers as it is with spaces. When I read it with read.csv or data.table header with space gets replaced with dot.
Please help to solve this issue

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use

data = read.csv(file_name , check.names=FALSE)

Comment: you can accept it as solution. If it resolved your problem.